# jQuery not Showing Elements?

Tags: jquery, html

I have used `.hide()` on some HTML elements that I've created and would like for them to show as soon as the person checks the Yes option in the radio button that I've created. My jQuery is as follows

```
if (document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD7"]:checked').value == "Yes") {
    $("#weapons").show();
    $("#weaponfield").show();
    $("#weaponfield2").show();
    $("#weaponfield3").show();
    $("#weaponfield4").show();
}
```

For some reason, when I select the "Yes" option, the elements will not `.show();`.

Anyone out there?

**UPDATE**
I have managed to fix this entire problem. I appreciate those who tried to help me! I have created my own fix though as none of the other methods worked.I assigned each input an ID and just called the ID to be hidden on a click function, very simple, lol!
Here is my jQuery:

```
            $("#weaponyes").click(function() {
                $("#weapons").show();
                $("#weaponfield").show();
                $("#weaponfield2").show();
                $("#weaponfield3").show();
                $("#weaponfield4").show();
            });

            $("#weaponno").click(function() {
                $("#weapons").hide();
                $("#weaponfield").hide();
                $("#weaponfield2").hide();
                $("#weaponfield3").hide();
                $("#weaponfield4").hide();
            });
```

This seemed to work perfectly, thanks!

Comment: why dont you use $('input[name="FIELD7"]:checked').val()

Comment: Because there is a "No" option as well as a "Yes" option. And I'm not too familiar with the .val(). Can you clarify how it would help my situation?

Comment: You can replace the query selector

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/shiv91/ngnb9at8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use on `change` event then check if the input radio is being checked by using `if ($("input[name='FIELD7']").is(":checked"))`

**JS**

```
$("input[name='FIELD7']").on("change", function() {
    if ($("input[name='FIELD7']").is(":checked"))
      $("#weapons").show();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3j3k179d/)

**After seeing your recent comment I added an update:**

```
$("input[name='FIELD7']").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() == 'Yes')
      $("#weapons").show();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3j3k179d/2/)

**Update when No is selected then hide:**

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name='FIELD7']").on("change", function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() == 'Yes')
          $("#weapons").show();
        else
          $("#weapons").hide();  
    });   
});
```

**CSS**

Hide elements by default.

```
#weapons, 
#weaponfield,
#weaponfield2,
#weaponfield3,
#weaponfield4 {
  display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3j3k179d/4/)

Comment: Thanks but here's another one. How would I do it for the "No" selector if it also has the name "FIELD7"?

Comment: @burger97979 If "No" is being checked, it should hide the divs right?

Comment: @burger97979 Great! Glad it helped.

Comment: Wait. One moment. I just noticed that whenever I input the code, the divs just showed and never hid or showed again. But I am about to go to sleep and will check your reply in the morning! :(

Comment: @burger97979 Ok I've updated my post. Outlining my update, put the Jquery code inside `$(function() { });` so it will be executed once the elements has been fully loaded. Then on your `css`, add `display:none` to those elements you wished to hide by default.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I made myself a fix. It was very simple XD! I still appreciate all the work you went through to try and help me!

Answer (score 1):

you can use is too. it should helps you. for me it did

```
 if ($("input[name='FIELD7']").is(":checked")){

    $("#weapons").show();
    $("#weaponfield").show();
    $("#weaponfield2").show();
    $("#weaponfield3").show();
    $("#weaponfield4").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple condition

```
var a=document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD7"]:checked');
```

Now in your code you could check in your condition

```
if(a!=null)
    {
        if (document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD7"]:checked').value == "Yes") 
        {
            $("#weapons").show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this entire problem. I appreciate those who tried to help me! I have created my own fix though as none of the other methods worked.I assigned each input an ID and just called the ID to be hidden on a click function, very simple, lol!
Here is my jQuery:

```
            $("#weaponyes").click(function() {
                $("#weapons").show();
                $("#weaponfield").show();
                $("#weaponfield2").show();
                $("#weaponfield3").show();
                $("#weaponfield4").show();
            });

            $("#weaponno").click(function() {
                $("#weapons").hide();
                $("#weaponfield").hide();
                $("#weaponfield2").hide();
                $("#weaponfield3").hide();
                $("#weaponfield4").hide();
            });
```

This seemed to work perfectly, thanks!